# How to compare 2 variables in cshell

Tags: linux, csh, tcsh

```
echo $a
18.9142
echo $b
18.9593
```

What i want to do is if a is less than b then echo "YES"

Please explain when to use "" , () , `` , {} , bc -l
in if-else statements.

```
echo $a
18.9142
echo $b
18.9593
```

What i have tried:

```
1.if ( "$a" < "$b") then
if: Badly formed number.

2.if (` "$a" < "$b" `) then
18.9142: Command not found.
if? echo "YES"
if? endif

3.if [` "$a" < "$b" `] then
18.9142: Command not found.
if: Expression Syntax.

4.if ["$a" < "$b"] then
18.9593]: No such file or directory.

5.if ["$a" < "$b"]; then
18.9593]: No such file or directory.

6.if (`echo "$a" < "$b" | bc -l`) then
if: Badly formed number.

7.if ( `echo "$a < $b" | bc -l` ) then

8.if [`echo "$a < $b" | bc -l`] then
[`echo "$a < $b" | bc -l`]: No match.

9.if [`echo "$a < $b" | bc -l`]; then
[`echo "$a < $b" | bc -l`]: No match.
then: Command not found.

10.if [`echo "$a < $b" | bc -l`];
[`echo "$a < $b" | bc -l`]: No match.
```

None of these seem to be working can anyone please help.

What i want to do is if a is less than b then echo "YES"
Please share approach in tcsh and bash.

Please explain when to use "" , () , `` , {} , bc -l
in if else statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment, but I need the space and formmating of an answer

```
#!/bin/csh -vx
set a=18.7
set b=19.3

if ( `echo "$a < $b" | bc -l` == 0 ) then
    echo OK
else
    echo no
endif
if ( `echo "$a < $b" | bc -l` ) then
    echo OK
else
    echo no
endif
```

When this is in a file it works correctly with or without the `== 0` portion in the test. Be sure to mark the file as executable with `chmod +x myTest.csh` (of course insert your script name for `myTest.csh`)

Note also that csh supports an simplified test

```
  if ( `echo "$a < $b" | bc -l` == 0 ) echo no
```

allowing one command after the closing `)`.

Don't have time to research further now. Maybe this will help you move forward, but the real advise is Abandon CSH! Search for csh-why-not.

IHTH.